# Displaying different navigation buttons depending on what is displayed (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, navigation

I have a number of medical products to display one at a time in a lightbox. Each product has 2 types of textual content attached to it: general and legal. By default, the general content is displayed.

Now, when this content (general) is displayed, I want a programatically generated rightward arrow link that, once clicked, displays the other type of content (legal) while hiding the general content.

When this happens, I also want the arrow to change from rightward to leftward, and of course when that new arrow is clicked, the legal content would in turn disappear, make the general content appear again, and the arrow would return to its initial state (rightward, triggering appearance of legal and disappearance of general).

I was thinking about the `toggle()` function but I can't figure out how to use it in this case. Any suggestion?

Comment: This sounds great but still we need to see some code or better if you could create an example of it in http://jsfiddle.net.